# How to use woocommerce with an API instead Wordpress DB

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, wordpress, oracle, woocommerce

I like the features of Woocommerce and the extensibility that you won with this plugin. I saw that Woocommerce actually has a **REST API**, but is there another way to make the things more seamlessly and simple. I would like to have these features but with the data of my **API** or **Backend-Database**, not the other way, because actually others Apps consume my current API.

This is an overview of the architecture of my app (I exclude other stuff like Load Balancers, cache servers, CDN, etc... for making things simple).

- **SERVER ONE (front-end -- public ip)**

  E-commerce Website (Wordpress with Woocommerce)
- **SERVER TWO (front-end DB -- private ip)**

  MySQL Database for **SERVER ONE**
- **SERVER THREE (Back-end -- private ip)**

  E-commerce App (Rails)
- **SERVER FOUR (Back-end -- private ip)**

  Oracle Database for **SERVER THREE**
- **SERVER FIVE (Back-end -- private ip)**

  API based on **SERVER THREE** E-commerce App

So, in general, I would like to know if there is a way to still use Woocommerce in my E-commerce Wordpress site either with the **API** of **SERVER FIVE** or a direct access to the **Oracle Database** of **SERVER FOUR**.

Answer (score 0):

We have integrated Woocommerce and Oracle. We don't use rest or the api, we talk directly from Oracle to the Woocommerce MySQL database. We have setup an Oracle database link using ODBC to the MySQL database and we read and write from Oracle to MySQL. We also have customised Woocommerce and talk directly from Woo to Oracle. As Woo is PHP there is no problem connecting to the Oracle database.
So for example we create(register) clients records from Oracle in WooCommerce and we pull orders out of Woocommerce and process them in Oracle with the ERP system.

Google database links Oracle and MySQL on how to set it up. One other hint, you will need the "SQLPASSTHROUGH" call if you need to do sql statements which require for example a mysql function. You also need to be aware that object names can be only a maximum of 29 characters in Oracle. So if you access a table in MySQL which has a long name you need to define a view with a shorter name for that table.